# How to .js file $ajax code defined '$ not defined error''?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var deneme = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
deneme.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js";
var nodeajax = document.createTextNode("function deneme() {console.log('dawdawdawd');$.ajax({ type: \"POST\", url: \"http://localhost:54371/checkbox.aspx/Check\", data: '{sayfa: 10 }', contentType: \"application/json; charset=utf-8\", dataType: \"json\", success: function (response) { console.log(response.d); alert('sdf'); }, failure: function (response) { console.log(response); } });}"););
deneme.appendChild(nodeajax);
document.body.appendChild(deneme);
```

How do I define ajax without using script tag in the .js file?

' $ is not defined.' I get an error.

Comment: You're appending your jQuery code (nodeajax) before you've appended the jQuery library. Trying swapping the order of your last 2 lines

Comment: Either you forgot to add jQuery script in your HTML source or you are trying to call JQuery method before it was added. Keep in mind to add important dependencies on top.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $ is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined)

Comment: Why are you appending code as text like that? I have never seen this practice before

Comment: @CarlBinalla I don't answer my question, because I don't use a script tag in the .js file.

Comment: @AlonEitan because I have to check the return value from web form with ajax

Comment: Try using two `script` element, instead of making the code a child of the `script` that holds the source link

Comment: @BrettGregson I tried and I get the same error

Comment: @CarlBinalla exactly how ?

Comment: @simgesen Are you aware [that you don't need jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery) in order to use AJAX?

Comment: Instead of appending `nodeajax` to `deneme`, create another one `var deneme_2 = document.createElement("SCRIPT");`, that's where you will append `nodeajax`

Comment: @Ivar Can you hint ?

Comment: @simgesen The link I added to my comment has a good explanation on how you can achieve that.

Comment: @CarlBinalla I tried but the result has not changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be solve your problem

```
var jqueryScript = document.createElement('script')
var ajaxScript = document.createElement('script')
jqueryScript.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js'
ajaxScript.innerHTML = `
window.onload = function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:54371/checkbox.aspx/Check",
    data: {sayfa: 10},
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      alert('sdf');
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
}
`
document.body.appendChild(jqueryScript)
document.body.appendChild(ajaxScript)
```

Here is the codepen [link](https://codepen.io/zeybek/pen/abzxvgG), it is working

Comment: Thanks but the function in the script does not work. It appears when the script is defined but does not work.

Comment: @simgesen I updated, check again

Comment: Thanks! I get bloked CORS access error when I apply the update.

Comment: You need to set `headers` on server side, server is blocking your POST requests. Check codepen link